# Set one element's top value equal to navbar's height

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and have the following code:

```
<nav class="navbar">
...
</nav>

<div class="progress-bar">
...
</div>
```

I want to set the .progress-bar's top value equal to the navbar's height. How can I achieve that?

Comment: With Javascript or a fixed height unfortunately.

Comment: Put it in (or directly below) the navbar element and adjust styling to support it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var navbarHeight = $('.navbar').height();
var progressBar = $('.progress-bar');
progressBar.css("top", navbarHeight);
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.navbar {
  height: 500px;
  background: yellow;
}

.progress-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar">
    ...
  </nav>

  <div class="progress-bar">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```